# How to get selecting data from the last 7 existing days?

Tags: mysql, sql

My problem: I have table with price and date. I need to have an average price from last 7 existing days. **E.g.: I have prices from today, yesterday, 30 days ago, 43 days ago etc. I need an average not from the last 7 days, but from the last 7 existing days.**

My code:

```
SELECT AVG(price) 
FROM table 
GROUP BY date  
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 7
```

But I have 7 average price from every day.
Maybe someone has another idea

Comment: Is the type of date `date` or `datetime`? If it's `datetime`, you may try to cast date to Date with CAST.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: I use mysql. Type of date isn't problem. I can change.

Comment: Maybe `SELECT AVG(price) FROM table WHERE (SELECT AVG(price) FROM table GROUP BY date  ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 7)` should work?

Comment: No. `#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery to get the last 7 existing days, get the earliest of those dates, then `join` that with the table.

```
SELECT AVG(price)
FROM table AS t1
JOIN (SELECT MIN(dateday) AS mindate
      FROM 
        (SELECT DATE(date) AS dateday
         FROM table
         GROUP BY dateday
         ORDER BY dateday DESC LIMIT 7
        ) AS x
      ) AS t2
ON t1.date >= t2.mindate
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your answer is the best for my case. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

use `avg` function and subquery

```
  select avg(price)
  from
    (SELECT date,price
     FROM table
     ORDER BY date desc limit 7
    ) as t
```

Comment: I don't need avg price from last 7 days. I need avg price from last 7 existing days. E.g. 2018-09-18, 2018-08-08, 2018-08-07, 2018-08-05, 2018-07-25, 2018-07-22, 2018-07-20, because the price was added on these days.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your answer is almost good. I have an average of the last 7 existing days in your code. And this is correct. But I need to take into account that there may be several prices on one day. I forgot to write about it